# Is this mathematical explanation of "except" and "other than" right?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions

This question is derived from this [one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/224918/95385).

Assume "not including" and "including" have two mutually exclusive meanings. It is impossible "not including" and "including" at the same time.

The [Oxford dict](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/except) gives this example of **except**.

> They work every day **except** Sunday

In the form of set (math), we have 2 sets in there

- on set_1 = {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday} they work
- on set_2 = {Sunday} they don't work

set_1 is **not including** Sunday, this is what "except" does mean, "other than" has the same meaning. Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, except means everything but that thing, i.e. not including.
Except Sunday would mean all the days but not Sunday.

Oxford dictionary defines "[except](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/except)" as

> not including; other than.