# When talk about an example sentence, which preposition should I use,"of", "about" or "for"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I asked a [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/225108/95385) just now

> The Oxford dict gives this example of **except**.

"except" is the word I was considering. I searched it on Oxford dict, and got the sentence above.

Is the sentence an example **of** the word "except"

or

**for** the word "except"

or

**about** the word "except"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example** is usually paired with **of**. See [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20example%20of%2C%20an%20example%20about%2C%20an%20example%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20example%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20example%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20example%20for%3B%2Cc0).

Usually, it's an example of [a noun].

- Your dog is an example of good training.
- That poem is a good example of a haiku.
- My cookbook has several examples of French cooking.

More rarely, we can have "**example for**" in sentences like:

- You need to set a good example for your younger siblings.
- This merger sets an example for other companies to follow.

"**Example about**" is uncommon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "an example of [a noun]" is a good formula to help me to understand the usage though, **except** is [a preposition]. Does the formula apply too?

Comment: I should have said noun or noun-phrase. "Except" here isn't functioning as a preposition. It's functioning as shorthand for "the word 'except' " so the general rule does apply in this case.