# Is it idiomatic to say "searched something on a online dictionary"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I asked a [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/225115/95385) just now

> "except" is the word I was considering. I searched it on Oxford dict, and got the sentence above.

[The Oxford dict](https://www.lexico.com/) is an online dictionary. When I searched something , is it idiomatic to say "searched something on the Oxford dictionary"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally *search **on** the Internet* and if the dictionary is online, it is idiomatic to say...

> I searched the word *on* an online dictionary ~ as your title reads

On the other hand, if you, for instance, have a paperback dictionary you say -

> I searched the word *in* the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can use the verb ***[to google:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/google)***

> to search for (something on the internet) using a search engine.
>
> - I googled the word on online dictionaries.

(Collins Dictionary)