# Is this a common expression, "the person addressed"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

This question is derived from this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/224916/95385), where someone says

> By "the person addressed" I meant the person to whom the question is addressed, the person who must answer the question.

One of the meanings on the [Oxford dict](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/address) is

> Speak to (a person or an assembly)

the corresponding example sentence is

> ‘The person obviously wasn't addressing him, but speaking to someone else.’

Does "address" in "address a question to someone" have the same meaning of "Speak to (a person or an assembly)"?

Is this a common expression, “the person addressed”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "address" in "address a question to someone" isn't used quite correctly. The verb "address" (in **sense 2** in your Oxford dictionary) takes, as its direct object, a noun meaning, or implying, a person or a group of people: an assembly, for example, or a meeting, or the House of Commons. Although "address a question to someone" would be understood, you can't address an inanimate object. Although 'House of Commons' is inanimate the implied meaning is the *people* in the House of Commons. (Even *they* are fairly inanimate :-)

I think you are confusing it with **sense 1** in the same dictionary. This usage *does* take an inanimate object. Their first example of *that* usage - "I addressed my letter to him personally" - means "I wrote *his* name and address on the envelope (not, for example, his company's name and address)"

Instead of "address a question to someone" you might **direct** a question *at* someone.

Comment: I am not confusing **sense 2** with **sense 1**, I just feel something uncommon when read "the person addressed". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @fu DL But your question asked about "address a question to someone", not "the person addressed"!

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I've updated the OP